# Entity framework LINQ speed converting SQL data into C# objects

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a fairly complex query written in LINQ which queries my database. I have made sure that I am only pulling back the relevant columns from each entity, so the query is as slim as it can be, and therefore the object which LINQ populates does not contain any unnecessary columns either.

If I run the LINQ query's resulting SQL against the DB directly, the SQL runs in about 4 seconds. However, doing this from my LINQ query takes about 25 seconds. The majority of this 25 seconds is taken up by the returned DB data being written into objects.

Are there any useful tricks which will help LINQ/Entity Framework out when performing this part of the operation?

Edit:

The long delay occurs when I call the ToList() method in the query below:

```
var q1 = from u in etc.Users
         where (u.flags & (int)UserFlags.Student) == (int)UserFlags.Student
         && (ariStudents.Contains(u.id) || ariStudents.Count == 0)
         && (from ua in etc.UserAssociations where ua.datasetId == datasetId && ua.userId == u.id && ua.type == (int)UserAssocTypes.EnrolActive select ua).Any()
         orderby u.id
         select new ElightsRaw2
         {
             Student = new ElrStudent{StudentId = u.id},
             StudentData = (
                    from sd in etc.StudentDatas
                    where sd.userId == u.id
                    && sd.datasetId == datasetId
                    select new ElrStudentData { attP = sd.attP, attA = sd.attA, attL = sd.attL }
                ).FirstOrDefault(),
             ElightOverall = (
                    from els in etc.eLightsStudents
                    where els.datasetId == datasetId
                    && els.userId == u.id
                    select els
                ).FirstOrDefault(),
             Groups = (
                 // get all courses and groups for user
                    from c in etc.Cours
                    join g in etc.Groups on c.id equals g.courseId
                    join ua in etc.UserAssociations on g.id equals ua.fkId
                    where ua.datasetId == datasetId
                    && ua.userId == u.id
                    && ua.type == (int)UserAssocTypes.EnrolActive
                    && (ua.flags & (int)UserAssociationFlags.AssociationDeleted) == 0
                    && (c.flags & (int)CourseFlags.Deleted) == 0
                    select new ElrGroupHolder
                    {
                        CourseName = c.name,
                        GroupName = g.name,
                        Breakdown = new ElrGroupHolderBreakdown
                        {
                            UnitsBelowScoreThresh1 = (
                                    from uus in etc.UserUnitScores
                                    join un in etc.Units on uus.unitId equals un.id
                                    join cu in etc.CourseUnits on un.id equals cu.unitId
                                    where uus.userId == u.id
                                    && (un.flags & (int)UnitFlags.Deleted) == 0
                                    && (cu.flags & (int)CourseUnitFlags.NotStarted) == 0
                                    && cu.courseId == c.id
                                    && (uus.performance > -1 && uus.performance <= amberThresh)
                                    && !(from exc in etc.UserAssociations where exc.userId == u.id && exc.fkId == un.id && exc.type == (int)UserAssocTypes.ExcludedUnit select exc).Any()    // not excluded from unit
                                    select uus
                                ).Count(),
                            UnitsBelowScoreThresh2 = (
                                    from uus in etc.UserUnitScores
                                    join un in etc.Units on uus.unitId equals un.id
                                    join cu in etc.CourseUnits on un.id equals cu.unitId
                                    where uus.userId == u.id
                                    && (un.flags & (int)UnitFlags.Deleted) == 0
                                    && (cu.flags & (int)CourseUnitFlags.NotStarted) == 0
                                    && cu.courseId == c.id
                                    && (uus.performance > -1 && uus.performance <= redThresh)
                                    && !(from exc in etc.UserAssociations where exc.userId == u.id && exc.fkId == un.id && exc.type == (int)UserAssocTypes.ExcludedUnit select exc).Any()    // not excluded from unit
                                    select uus
                                ).Count(),
                            CfcCount = (
                                    from cfc in etc.CFCs
                                    where cfc.datasetId == datasetId
                                    && cfc.studentId == u.id
                                    && cfc.dt > dCfcCutoff
                                    && cfc.type == (int)CfcTypes.Concern
                                    && (cfc.flags & (int)CfcFlags.Deleted) == 0
                                    && (
                                        // only include attendance and behaviour CFCs
                                        (cfc.flags & (int)CfcFlags.Attendance) == (int)CfcFlags.Attendance
                                        || (cfc.flags & (int)CfcFlags.Behaviour) == (int)CfcFlags.Behaviour
                                    )
                                    select cfc
                                ).Count(),
                            SrsScores = (
                                    from srs in etc.SRScores
                                    join sr in etc.SubReviews on srs.srId equals sr.id
                                    where sr.datasetId == datasetId
                                    && (sr.flags & (int)SrFlags.Deleted) == 0
                                    && (srs.flags & (int)SrsFlags.Deleted) == 0
                                    && sr.dt > dCfcCutoff
                                    && sr.userId == u.id
                                    && sr.courseId == c.id
                                    select new ElrSrScore
                                    {
                                        attainment = srs.attainment,
                                        attitude = srs.attitude,
                                        motivation = srs.motivation,
                                        studyskill = srs.studyskill
                                    }
                                ).ToList(),
                            ElightEnrolment = (
                                    from ele in etc.eLightsEnrolments
                                    where ele.datasetId == datasetId
                                    && ele.groupId == g.id
                                    && ele.userId == u.id
                                    select ele
                                ).FirstOrDefault(),
                        },
                        CourseAttendance = (
                                from a in etc.Attendances
                                where a.studentId == u.id
                                && a.courseId == c.id
                                && a.weekNumberId == null
                                && a.datasetId == datasetId
                                select a
                            ).FirstOrDefault()
                    }
                ).ToList(),
         };

return q1.ToList();
```

Comment: Can you share the query? Execution plan? Dataset size?

Comment: Query posted above. Execution plan is probably irrelevant since the query itself is fast. It's the part where it's converted to objects which suffers.

Comment: I see a lot of joins and firstordefaults. Do you not have navigation properties on your models? This query contains 10 different subqueries -- this is bound to take very long. When you execute that query, how many objects are actually contained? They have to be parsed into objects and sent across the network which could take long but this is *really* long.

Comment: When you mention navigation properties, are you talking about lazy-loading? If so this would be bad because the query returns around 14,000 objects. That would be a lot of round-trips to the database.

Comment: Navigational properties only use lazy loading if you mark them `virtual` -- without that they'll load eagerly. Are you saying your list returns 14.000 objects? So 14.000 objects x 10 queries per object means 140.000 queries and then translating every result into an object and transferring it over the network. Have you considered retrieving it in batches? E.g.: 50 userids each request? I think you're doing such an expensive operation that optimization might have to be searched in a different approach.

Comment: Just to clarify, this is 1 single query. It is one single round trip to the database. The single query returns data to populate 14,000 objects all at once. I just tried disabling AutoDetectChangesEnabled and it was super-fast, so I think I have found the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! I ran into something similar myself not to long ago. What I came up with is using the AsParallel() function within LINQ ... however this comes with a few caveats.

1. You will be running things in parallel - obvious but if your trying to do things in a non thread safe manner there could be issues
2. This will only be useful in certain cases - the way I got the most use out of it was when I was converting a lot of database rows into C# objects and doing it repetitively ... think foreach,for,while loops that don't have any decision logic in them but just a straight database row to C# class kind of conversion
3. It really only makes sense for "large" amounts of data - You're going to have to play around with this and see what the timing difference is but if you are just converting a handful of rows, the overhead for AsParallel() will actually cost you more time, not save you any.

Here is some more reading on AsParallel(), hope this helps!

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd413237%28v=vs.100%29.aspx - AsParallel Method

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997425%28v=vs.110%29.aspx - Intro to parallel queries

http://www.dotnetperls.com/asparallel - Good basic walkthrough of AsParallel

Comment: Parallelism isn't a solution for an unoptimized algorithm -- it just hides the issue which is bound to surface later on again. Unless it has been established that the algorithm is as good as it gets, you should focus on fixing that instead of the symptoms.

Comment: True but the question ended on: "Are there any useful tricks which will help LINQ/Entity Framework out when performing this part of the operation?". As my answer states using a parallel query comes with some caveats and I just went through the exact same problem on a project I recently completed so this answer is based on my own experience/fustration after doing everything else I could to trim down my SQL query, which the question also states has happened.

Comment: Hi Pseudonym - thanks very much for your reply. Just to clarity, the delay happens when I call the ToList() method on the IQueryable object which contains the LINQ. I tried adding AsParallel() before this, but it didn't make any difference. Thinking about it now, I'm not sure that it would do either.